# fish: Unknown command "abbr"

Tags: fish

Fish is not recognizing the `abbr` command.

```
fish: Unknown command “abbr”
abbr: command not found
```

In all other ways fish is behaving normally.

The [Fish documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html) doesn't give any clues as to why this might happen.

Stack: EC2 Ubuntu machine, fish version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`abbr` was not in 2.0.0 - it was only added in 2.2.0, so that's why it isn't working!

You can install the latest available packages (currently 2.2.0, soon to be 2.3.0) from the [fish-shell Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fish-shell/+archive/ubuntu/release-2).